# github action how to run a job after another job timeoout

Tags: github, github-actions

I am tried to send a notice about the workflow's timeout, then I tried with this workflow demo:

```
name: test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
jobs:
  build:
    timeout-minutes: 1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: test
        run: |
          while true; do echo 1; sleep 1; done

  cancel:
    if: ${{ cancelled() }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: cancel
        run: |
          echo "cancel"
```

but it seems like didn't trigger by timeout of job1, why?

about the descript of job on web page, it seems like be cancel:

```
Annotations
2 errors
build
The job running on runner GitHub Actions 2 has exceeded the maximum execution time of 1 minute.
build
The operation was canceled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
jobs:
  build:
    timeout-minutes: 1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: test
        run: |
          while true; do echo 1; sleep 1; done

  cancel:
    if: ${{ failure() }}
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: cancel
        run: |
          echo "cancel"
          echo "${{ needs.build.result }}"
```

I changed condition as result of build job is `failure` and added dependency between jobs.

[image]

Comment: it work, and I have another question, How can I share the varibales between two jobs? More specifically, I want to know how long the workflow be executed? I was tried to the the `env` at the top level with `env: START: $(date +%s)`, but it didn;t work

Comment: I found a solution, just use the `output` on the job then it's ok